# deno.json pre- and post- script options like npm

Tags: typescript, deno

In npm it is possible to have a script run before (`pre*`) or after (`post*`) a script (`*`). https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts

Is there a way to do the same for deno.json tasks?

Currently I'm handling it like this:

```json
{
  "tasks": {
    "start": "deno run -A --unstable --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts",
    "pretest": "jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' import_map.json unit.test.import_map.json > unit.test.import_map.gen.json",
    "test": "deno task pretest && deno test --allow-read --watch --import-map=unit.test.import_map.gen.json"
  },
  "importMap": "./import_map.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Deno's task runner does not support that pattern.

Apart from recent support for the Node.js ecosystem, Deno's historical philosophy has been to prefer explicit behavior over opaque and automatic/algorithmic defaults.

If you prefer the behavior of `npm`'s runner, you can use a `package.json` file to manage your tasks/scripts, and run them using `npm` — and whenever you find it convenient, Deno's task runner can also run individual scripts from that file — from [the manual](https://deno.com/manual@v1.33.2/tools/task_runner#packagejson-support):

> ### package.json support
>
> `deno task` falls back to reading from the `"scripts"` entries in a package.json file if it is discovered. Note that Deno does not respect or support any npm life cycle events like `preinstall` or `postinstall`—you must explicitly run the script entries you want to run (ex. `deno cache main.ts && deno task postinstall`).

---

Task runner refs:

- [manual](https://deno.com/manual@v1.33.2/tools/task_runner)
- [repo](https://github.com/denoland/deno_task_shell/)